# What does $_registered_pages do?

Tags: plugin-development, admin

I would like to know what $_registered_pages does and where am I supposed to use it.

Thanks.

p.s was unable to find any documentation on it online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_registered_pages` is a temporary container for all registered admin menu pages. It is filled in `add_menu_page()` and `add_submenu_page()` and used used later in `user_can_access_admin_page()`.

The leading underscore indicates you should **not use** it for anything. It is private and might change its name any time without warning. So do not use it in your own code, that will break one day.

Comment: I see thanks.
So if I want to add a few paths to "user_can_access list" (as I want to use them for form_actions) how can I go about doing it ?

Comment: Filter `'role_has_cap'` or change the capabilities for that menu page globally. We have examples for both on our site.